# Why does the "down" key behavior change in a Tkinter listbox after issuing selection_set and selection_clear commands?

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

When first launch the "down" key can be used to scroll through the list. When a letter key is pressed the "SelectItem" function is used to jump to the matching item using the selection_set and selection_clear and selection.see functions. For some reason after hitting this function and updating the list selection the down key now jumps to the previous selected item rather than scrolling to the next item in the list.

```
def SelectItem(event):

    for string in List:
        print event.keysym
        if event.keysym == string[0].lower() or event.keysym == string[0]:
            selection.selection_clear(0, END)
            selection.selection_set(List.index(string))
            selection.see(List.index(string))
            break

TK = Tkinter.TK()
selection = Tkinter.Listbox(TK, height = 8, width = 70, selectmode = EXTENDED)
selection.grid(row = 110, column = 50, sticky = W)
selection.bind("<KeyPress>", SelectItem)

global List
List =     ["apple", "banana", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "frog", "grape"]
for name in List:
    selection.insert(END, name)

mainloop()
```

I would like to preserve the function of the "down" key in a listbox after updating a listbox's selection. Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted has lots of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the listbox needs to move the cursor down or up, it always starts with the "active" item, which essentially means which item has the keyboard focus.

You need to set the active item at the same time you set the selection. For example:

```
selection.activate(List.index(string))
```